# How to backup old data in database month-wise or couple-of-month-wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have a project using Microsoft SQL Server and SSMS to access it in the backend as admin. We have been using this database since 8 months and a lot of data already exists in it spread over numerous tables. Around 5000 entries from users, gets added up over a months time.

Now, my need is to make backup of database for every two months starting from day 1 of its usage. Lets say, I want to make backup of all the data in the database that was there in the database

- from July 1st - August 31st,
- from September 1st - October 31st, etc.

New to using SSMS. I found solutions to backup database at that moment. But not for old data segregated by date range like my requirement. Any tips or solutions are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, you're asking how to "backup" data from your *current* database (i.e. today) that was only present in the database months ago? If so, then you have a misunderstanding about how database backups work. SQL Server is not an Event Sourcing database (disregarding Temporal Tables here) so you cannot go back in time as you're describing (for example, you cannot "undelete" data that was present months ago that was since deleted without having a prior backup already made.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, what you want is near impossible. It is best just to perform a full backup of your database

Comment: @Dai: Sorry if my description created some misunderstanding. I dont want to undelete. All the data from June 1st till today exists on my current database. But i want to make backup of this 8th months data in batches of 2 months. Lets say, for audit purpose. We need to create a backup every two months and store it in some place. We forgot to start doing it from the beginning. Hence this requirement. I hope I am clear now. Kindly feel free to edit my question if its giving wrong meaning.

Comment: you will need to understand the database design and relationship of each tables. And data usually aren't simply able to partition by a `date`.

Comment: What's the point in having 2 monthly batches of backup data. What can't you do with a full backup

Comment: @Squirrel : Yeah, thats right. All my tables dont have creation date. Some have and some dont. But I was thinking if some snapshot is maintained by default and if we can make use of and create backup. 
But as LJ01 said, I will create backups regularly and provide the data to management based on their date range whenever its needed. Auditors need ready data to prove the reports. So non technical team needed it to be backed up separately that way.